Integration of $\int \frac{2a^2+x^2 + b x\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{(c+b x^2)\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+ x(a^2 +x^2)} dx$
I try to solve the following integral
$$\int \frac{2a^2+x^2 + b x\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{(c+b x^2)\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+ x(a^2 +x^2)} dx, $$
where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$.
My attempt:
By the change of variation $x=a \tan t$,  where $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le t \le \frac{\pi}{2} $, we obtain:
$$\int \frac{2 \cos^2 t + \sin^2 t + b \sin t}{c \cos^3 t + b a^2 \sin^2 \cos t + a^2\sin t \cos t }dt. $$
Then by using the change of variation $
z = \tan \frac{t}{2} $ we get:
$$\frac{1+bz +b z^3 + z^4}{(1-z^2)(cz^4 + 2a^2z^3+(4 b a^2- 2 c)z^2 + 2a^2z+c)}dz. $$
Therefore we can write:
$$\int \frac{2z}{1- z^2}dz+ \int\frac{2 c z^3 +(4ba^2-2c)z + 4a^2}{(cz^4 + 2a^2z^3+(4 b a^2- 2 c)z^2 + 2a^2z+c)} dz. $$
Since the denominator is a polynomial of degree  4 and it is not decomposable, I stopped!
Is my solution correct?  If it is not,  what solution can be used?
Thanks for any help.

It would help to know where the integral came from - was it given in a context where you'd expect it to have a simple antiderivative?

Looking only at your final expression (i.e. making no comment on whether you took the right approach or did all the substitutions correctly), it is possible to factorise the quartic expression in the denominator because of the symmetry in its coefficients. One way to do so would be as follows:
$$\begin{eqnarray} c z^4 + 2a^2 z^3 + (4ba^2 - 2c) z^2 + 2a^2 z + c & = & c z^2 \left[ \left(z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2} \right) + \frac{2a}{c} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) + \frac{4ba^2}{c} - 2 \right] \\
& = & cz^2 \left[ \left(z + \frac{1}{z} \right)^2 + \frac{2a^2}{c} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) + \frac{4ba^2}{c} - 4 \right] \\
& = & cz^2 (Z^2 + \frac{2a}{c} Z + \frac{4ba^2}{c} - 4) & \mbox{where } Z = z + \frac{1}{z} \\
& = & cz^2 (Z + \alpha + \beta)(Z + \alpha - \beta) & \mbox{where } \alpha = \frac{a^2}{c}, \beta = \frac{\sqrt{a^4 - 4a^2bc + 4c^2}}{c} \\
& = & c(z^2 + (\alpha + \beta)z + 1)(z^2 + (\alpha - \beta)z + 1) \end{eqnarray}$$
This factorises that quartic into a pair of quadratics (which both have real coefficients as long as $a^4 - 4a^2bc + 4c^2 \geq 0$), from which you can then do a further factoring and/or partial fraction decomposition.
This also assumes that $c \neq 0$, but if $c = 0$ then the quartic collapses down to $2a^2 z^3 + 4b a^2 z^2 + 2a^2 z = 2a^2 z(z^2 + 4b z + 1)$ which is even easier to factorise.

Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Result: The integral evaluates to
\begin{align}
I=&\int \frac{2a^2+x^2 + b x\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{(c+b x^2)\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+ x(a^2 +x^2)} dx\\
=&\ \frac{r_++d}{r_+-r_-}\ln\bigg( x+\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{r_+}\bigg)
+ \frac{r_-+d}{r_--r_+}\ln\bigg( x+\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{r_-}\bigg)\tag1
\end{align}
with $d=\frac{a^2}c$ and $r_\pm = \frac12\left( d\pm \sqrt{d^2-4bd+4}\right)$.
Proof: Employ the substitution
$x=a\sinh t$ instead
\begin{align}
I=& \ d\int \frac{\sinh^2t+b \sinh t\cosh t+2}
{bd \sinh^2t+d \sinh t\cosh t+ 1}\ dt\\
= & \ d\int \frac{2\coth^2t+b \coth t-1}
{\coth^2t+d \coth t+bd-1}\ dt\\ 
=& \ d \int \frac{2\coth^2t+b \coth t-1}
{(\coth t+ r_+) (\coth t+ r_-)}\ dt\\
=& \ \frac{r_++d}{r_+-r_-}\int \frac{1+r_+\coth t}{\coth t + r_+}dt
+ \frac{r_-+d}{r_--r_+} \int \frac{1+r_-\coth t}{\coth t + r_-}dt\\
=&\ \frac{r_++d}{r_+-r_-}\ln\bigg( \sinh t+\frac{\cosh t}{r_+}\bigg)
+ \frac{r_-+d}{r_--r_+}\ln\bigg( \sinh t+\frac{\cosh t}{r_-}\bigg)
\end{align}
Then, reverse-substitute to obtain the result (1).
